# How to use push notifications in cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have some strange problem... I'm using push notifications for messaging in my Ionic app but it works from time to time... My code is:

```
public initPushNotification() {
    if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        console.warn('Cordova is not available - Run in physical device. Push notifications not initialized.');

        return;
    }

    let zone = new NgZone({ enableLongStackTrace: false });

    zone.run(() => {
        this.Push.hasPermission().then((res: any) => {
            if (res.isEnabled) {
                const options: PushOptions = {
                    android: {
                        senderID: GOOGLE_FCM_ID
                    }
                };

                let push_object = this.Push.init(options);

                push_object.on('registration').subscribe((data: any) => {
                    this.APIRequest.post('/messages/register-fcm-token', data).subscribe(response => {
                        console.log(response)
                    }, err => {
                        console.log(err)
                    })

                    console.log('push.registration', data);
                });

                push_object.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
                    console.log('push.notification', data);

                    this.events.publish('messages:push', data.message);
                });

                push_object.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
            } else {
                alert('We do not have permission to send push notifications');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

It is located in `app.component.ts`.

Some of behavior:

1. Works fine when app is minimized on `Cat S60` phone
2. Some times works when app is minimized on some cheap `Huawei`
3. Some time works on both devices when app is opened as it should be. In most times not.

When I send it to Google I receive back `OK` status.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one signal for notifications. It's fast and effective. You can get detailed information from the links below.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/cordova-sdk-setup

https://www.npmjs.com/package/onesignal-cordova-plug

http://www.plugreg.com/plugin/one-signal/onesignal-cordova-sdk